# How to iterate over the all the header tags in a specific div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to iterate over all the header tags in a specific div tag?  I'm trying to automatically create a document map tree of everything in my div tag and place it in a sidebar menu...  If there's an easy to use javascript library... i would like that approach as well because then i wouldn't need to write any javascript code...

```js
$( document ).ready( readyFn );

function readyFn( jQuery ) {
    //alert("hey!");
    var docmap = $("#docmap");
    var body   = $("#body");
    docmap.append('<br>Some new content!');
 
    var all = body.getElementsByTagName("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");

    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        docmap.append(all[i].innerHtml);
    }  
}
```

```css
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: 200px; 
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="docmap">
   <ul>
      <li> hello
      <li> hi
      <li> howdy
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
   <h1>header1</h1>
   <h2>header2 a</h2>
   <h2>header2 b</h2>
   <h1>header1 a</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `body.getElementsByTagName("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");` should be `body.find("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");` as `body` is a jQuery object.  jQuery does not have native finders exposed on it.

Comment: and then `.each()` ?

Comment: _vanillaJS_ would be `document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');`.

Comment: Why are we mixing jQuery and DOM, pick one and stick to it.

Comment: Granted, I'm not sure how this logic is expected to work, even with the correct syntax, as there is no `#body` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to get the elements and then loop over them.

```js
$( document ).ready( readyFn );

function readyFn( $ ) {
    var docmap = $("#docmap");
    var body   = $("#body");
    docmap.append('<br>Some new content!');
 
    var all = body.find("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");
    
    all.each(function(){
      docmap.append(this.innerHTML);
    });
}
```

```css
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: 200px; 
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="docmap">
   <ul>
      <li> hello
      <li> hi
      <li> howdy
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
   <h1>header1</h1>
   <h2>header2 a</h2>
   <h2>header2 b</h2>
   <h1>header1 a</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,  that works great... one further quetion, how do you get the name of the tag instead of the innerHtml?  for example if(this.name == "h1") then..., if(this.name=="h2") then...

Comment: `tagName` is the Element property @pico  `this.tagName === 'H1'`